# Is there a quicker way to change blender UI Resolution Scale?

Tags: modeling

Are there any addons or keyboard shortcuts which exist which allow you to change blender UI resolution scale quickly?

I am frequently hooking up my laptop to my external screen and the scale is mismatched when switching between the two - thus the reason for wanting a quick switch.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save it as *.py file and install as an add-on. This add-on will check the screen resolution (if you are using Windows) and change scale after a file is loaded (basically on startup)

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "UI scale",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Interface",
}


import bpy
import ctypes
from bpy.app.handlers import persistent

@persistent
def load_handler(dummy):
    
    user32 = ctypes.windll.user32
    screensize = user32.GetSystemMetrics(0), user32.GetSystemMetrics(1)
    prefs = bpy.context.preferences.view

    # fill in your resolution here:
    if screensize == (1920,1080):
        # and scale that you want:
        prefs.ui_scale = 1.2
    else:
        # and default scale:
        prefs.ui_scale = 1.0



def register():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.append(load_handler)
    # uncomment to go nuts and check on every change 
    # bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(load_handler)

def unregister():
    bpy.app.handlers.load_post.remove(load_handler)
    # uncomment to go nuts and check on every change 
    # bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.remove(load_handler)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 2):

Try holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and scrolling up and down, or clicking in the middle mouse button and moving the mouse up and down (while still holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>).

Either option must be performed over a menu within the UI (such as the <kbd>N</kbd> key menu of the 3D Viewport or the Properties Panel)