# Change the resolution scale on the fly by shortcuts?

Tags: python, interface, add-on, shortcut

ctrl + alt + Q    and     ctrl + space
are great Shotcuts!

When I maximize the Outliner for example I would prefer a 2.0 or 1.5 resolution scale. Or ingeneral when I maximize a window a changed resolution scale would be handy.

So I am totally new to Python, but I am quite sure setting up a script/addon that quickly does the following should actually be quite simpel:

ctrl +1 = interface resolution scale 1

ctrl +2 = interface resolution scale 1.5

ctrl + 3 = interface resolution scale 2

Or even more advanced:

Or mouse wheel + ctrl + alt + rotating it = 0.5....1...2...5 interface resolution scale "on the fly"

I am also planning on reacording tutorials where changing the interface scale on the fly/quickly would be handy, too.

Could anyone guide me the direction how to accomplish this? I already found parts of the script needed here:
[Is there a quicker way to change blender UI Resolution Scale?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/261911/is-there-a-quicker-way-to-change-blender-ui-resolution-scale)

Actually all I would need to build upon would be a standard script listening for keys so I can add the following command.

```
    prefs.ui_scale = 1.5 ...
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can't help with your question, but be aware that the Ctrl-1,2,3,  etc. hotkeys are already in use to add Subdivision Surface modifiers to objects with differing subdivision levels.

Answer (score 2):

After running the script, go to viewport,
`ctrl` + `mouse_wheel_up`: Resolution Scale + 0.1
`ctrl` + `mouse_wheel_down`: Resolution Scale - 0.1
**(Go to keymap settings, make sure there are no shortcut conflicts)**
**(Scroll wheel shortcut doesn't work on Outliner, you need to change shortcut if using on Outliner)**

```
import bpy
from bpy.utils import register_class, unregister_class

class SCALE_RES_UP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.scale_res_up"
    bl_label = "Resolution Scale Up"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        try:
            bpy.context.preferences.view.ui_scale += 0.1
        except: pass
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SCALE_RES_DN(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.scale_res_dn"
    bl_label = "Resolution Scale Down"

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        try:
            bpy.context.preferences.view.ui_scale -= 0.1
        except: pass
        return {'FINISHED'}

classes = (SCALE_RES_UP, SCALE_RES_DN)
addon_keymaps = []
def register():
    for cls in classes: register_class(cls)

    # Add the hotkey
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Screen')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.scale_res_up", type='WHEELUPMOUSE', value='PRESS', ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("view3d.scale_res_dn", type='WHEELDOWNMOUSE', value='PRESS', ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():
    for cls in classes: unregister_class(cls)

    # Remove the hotkey
    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Example to make a script to add-on: [How to duplicate parented objects as one object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263081/how-to-duplicate-parented-objects-as-one-object)